# Best Database for Windows Server 2008 R2 with SQL 2005

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ms-access, windows-server-2008

I'm writing the entire database system for a factory, this includes inventory, payroll, incoming and outgoing shipments, job-data, customers, etc. The database will be stored offsite on a server running Windows 2008 R2 with SQL 2005. The guy who runs the server sent me this too:

> "We also have quickbooks installed on the server and we have Exchange 2010 running.  The terminal server is also ws 2008 R2.
>
> There is plenty of horsepower on the primary exchange/file server.  Let me know if you have any other questions.".

I know my boss uses Quickbooks to look at reports and stuff like that. I'm not sure how relevant exchange 2010 is, nor what the significance of "terminal server is also ws 2008 r2" is. My boss wants me to write the entire system in ms access 2010, but I feel like this will be a lot more work than simply writing it in MySQL. Will my boss still be able to look at his reports in quickbooks if we change the database to MySQL? What would be a good database technology to use? I feel the most comfortable writing it in a scripting language using MySQL, but would still be happy if I could write it in something like C/C++. I've been trying to learn access, and it seems that setting up a front-end and back-end database in access would be a pain in the ass. There are going to be several sectors in the factory that will be using the client-side software to run queries and insertions into the database(I think around 5-6).

If I can write this thing in MySQL, I think I could do the whole thing fairly pain free, but I fear that I can't because it will be incompatible with Quickbooks and the previous database(Although I hear converting is fairly easy). Mostly just Quickbook compatibility is my problem.

How horrible would it be to write this thing in Ruby?

Thank you, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with MS Access front-end on SQL backend?

Comment: Is this where you split the database? I thought access always ran on an SQL backend. My biggest problem is that most of the insertions are going to be done with barcode scanners, and I feel like I could benefit from the flexibility of writing it in a programming language. I need it to automatically run a query each time it scans

Do you know an easy way to do an SQL backend? I assume this means I would make forms in MS access that would communicate with the SQL server?

Comment: MS Access is very powerful.  It has a programming language called `VBA` or `Visual Basic for Applications`, from which you can implement all sorts of custom logic and business rules.  Plus designing forms is very quick and easy.  And it has built-in features for connecting to SQL Server back-end data.  However it will take some time to get familiar with the environment and tooling.  For a large, but functionally simple application in a local-only environment, it is probably worth the time investment.

Comment: Alright, then maybe I'll do MS access with an SQL backend. Do you think it will be possible to get it to run a VBA script each time a barcode is scanned? The database will not be local, but essentially all the clients will be.

Comment: Should be no problem.  [Here's](http://www.ehow.com/how_6887186_read-data-ms-access-databases.html) a tutorial on eHow.  When you have a field selected and hit the scan button, the numbers in the barcode will be entered into the field.  Then you can use the Access OnChange event to run some VBA.  This sounds like a big job - I hope they gave you about 6-months to do it.

Comment: It's the biggest job I've done yet, then again I'm only 20. I'm pretty sure there is no deadline, but I'd like to finish it within a month. I think I can do it. I've programmed much more complex systems in MySQL before, the only problem I'm having is getting used to MS-ACCESS and using a barcode scanner for the first time. Thanks very much for the tutorial, as well as pointing me towards a event-driven approach(which I'm very familiar with).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickbooks can use MySQL as a datasource (or just about anything else), but you'll need to make your database conform to the Quickbooks way of doing things: i.e., your tables will need to match the QB table structures.  It sounds like you just need a front end (data entry forms and reports) and a custom back-end.  Access can quickly turn into a nightmare if you don't put in some up-front design thought, but it does give you forms & reports & web pages free in a neat little package.  Make sure you use an Access Data Project (adp) that's connected to a SQL Server back end.  Access does have its own native database, but everything gets stored in one local file and it's not good for applications that will be accessed by multiple people in multiple locations.  It also gets complicated when you need to make a change and roll it out to all of your users.

Another option is to look into a customizable web platform, like SalesForce or MS Dynamics.  That will also let you create your own tables, forms, and reports, and updates are immediate for all users, but you'll have ongoing monthly user fees.  They look great on a resume, though!

Comment: Thanks again, I'll just have to look into this. I think I've decided I'm going to use an SQL backend, and try to use Access for each client.

Comment: Quickbooks can run on top of MySQL?  Since when?  Link, please!

Comment: Sorry @Larry, I misspoke (mistyped?): you can connect to the Quickbooks back end with a read-only odbc driver, giving you the ability to use external reporting and analysis tools like Crystal, Excel, and Access.  You can also get a [commercial read/write driver](http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/articles/INF12836) that could be used to construct your own back end, but I suspect you'd still need to drive the data into the standard back-end.  It's more of a front-end development tool.

Answer (score 2):

I don't mean to be a spoil sport but there is a tremendous amount of naivety expressed in this question.  It's hard to imagine that you will be successful in designing and implementing such a large system without a basic knowledge of the technologies involved.

A few thoughts:

1. Quickbooks already covers most of the features you say you will be responsible for implementing.  Are you supplementing the existing Quickbooks system, replacing it, or what?
2. Quickbooks uses its own (extraordinarily slow) database engine.  It isn't "compatible" with SQL Server, MySQL, or Access.
3. SQL Server 2005 *is* a database.  You don't use a database *with* it, you use it *as* your database.  A Microsoft-centric organization such as the one you describe is not likely to be interested in installing yet another database server like MySQL.
4. MS Access encompasses both a database "engine" (called JET) and a desktop development environment.  The engine can be used with other development environments and the development environment can attach to other database engines (most often SQL Server, but others work too).  When you say the boss wants to write the system in MS Access you need to be clear whether he means the engine, the development environment or both.  (My guess is they want to use Access as the front-end development platform and SQL Server as the data store).
5. You will not write a system of this complexity in a month.  You probably won't even *design* it in that time.

Comment: It seems naive because it is, I don't have much experience with Microsoft products, I'm used to programming things myself. I feel like I'll be able to do it, I've developed systems much more complex, however using a platform I was familiar with.

Comment: 1: I'm not sure at all, I literally showed up at the factory, the guy walked me around telling me what he wanted me to do(Took about an hour), then we sat in his office and discussed it. He used Quickbooks to generate reports(I think, he didn't actually tell me). Most of what I'm doing is supplemented that which used to be done by hand(I couldn't believe it, they fill half a filing cabinet drawer a day with the shit they write down).

Comment: 2: Well, they were generating reports from an Access database with Quickbooks. They also used Excel a bit I think. I just wanted to make sure that having a MySQL database wouldn't make it impossible to do the same things he's doing. 

3: Oh, so SQL Server 2005 is a Microsoft product? Damn, didn't have a clue. I've ditched the MySQL idea mostly for this reason. I had a similar post like this earlier, and people told me to stay the hell away from Access; That in addition to my aversion towards the software made me not really want to use it.

Comment: 4. When he said he wanted me to write it in Ms Access I have no clue what part he meant. He doesn't know anything about these kinds of things, that's why he hired me. He doesn't even know the difference between backend and frontend. He didn't even tell me we were keeping it on a web server until days later, the whole time I thought we were keeping it onsite.

5. It's not that complex. A shipment comes in, we scan it which inserts the barcode into the table that corresponds to that specific sector. It will check for duplicates or presence in other tables as well.

Comment: It is also weighed, and the weight will be uploaded to the same row. That's honestly all that will really happen for the shipment part.

Each time a pallet is scanned, a workers information is also scanned. I'll have a table of workers, a table of current jobs, and a table of shipments.

Comment: When a shipment is weighed, that weight is added to the corresponding employees total weight. At the end of the day, the weight is totaled, and from that it can be determined how much they will make that day.

I will design a few forms for the supervisors, things like job reports, payroll, etc. I've designed payroll systems and the like before, the concept isn't complex, the implementation is just foreign.